# Interpreting the SKU/product code for hard disks

Tags: hard-drive

I always find it rather annoying that it's often the case that HDDs don't actually list the capacity on them in a human readable form (the single most useful bit of information).  I did come across a link that showed how the product SKUs for Seagate, Western Digital, etc are put together so you can interpret them.

I have a Seagate ST340014A here and I recall that some of the constituent parts of that SKU denote the capacity, speed, number of platters, etc.  Can anyone point me towards the explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is different for every manufacturer. I will try to update as I find them.

The product code is typically made from, model series, capacity, RPM and a few other IDs.

[Seagate see here](http://seagate.custkb.com/seagate/crm/selfservice/search.jsp?DocId=204763) (From fideli's answer)

Western Digital:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Wil.  I've just found it on the Seagate page: http://seagate.custkb.com/seagate/crm/selfservice/search.jsp?DocId=204763  (the key thing it seems was googling for 'model number' rather than sku or product code) so it looks like my disk is a 3.5" 40Gb ATA drive, which sounds about right.

Comment: @the_mandrill no problem, should of read the question better and just given you a direct answer!

Answer (score 3):

For Seagate, check out this [Knowledge Base article](http://seagate.custkb.com/seagate/crm/selfservice/search.jsp?DocId=204763). Although it's useful, that model number does not indicate anything about speed or number of platters. As much as I don't like solutions like this, it's far easier to just [Google the model number](http://www.google.ca/search?q=st340014a). For computer and electronic parts, this works well and generally leads to the [product specifications](http://www.seagate.com/staticfiles/support/disc/manuals/ata/100217279nBarr7200.7.pdf).